# About Android File permission

Tags: android

I want to read This directory's file data（file of about 80MB）

```
/storage/emulated/0/Download/Record_test.mp4
```

But when using File.length() Function, It returns "0", I can't understand it. Because of I have declared the relevant permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I'm sure this file exists！

Comment: You declared the permissions, are you sure you grant them? Your device running Android 10, 11 ...? , a lot of details are missing in your questions, please add them

Comment: On Android 11+, you do not have access to content in `Download/`, unless your app installation put that content there in the first place.

Comment: @CommonsWare First of all,Thank you to answer my question,But: I want to make a application like Netdisk. It needs select file with client's device,How to fix it ?